# Make tiled overview page of document pages

Tags: adobe-indesign, batch-processing

I am creating a multiple page file in inDesign and want to also create an overview page where every single page is represented by a tile/thumbnail on that page.

I am using batch processing to create this multiple page document and I have over 300 pages. Is there a way to automate the process of creating and adding the thumbnails?

Comment: Hi drmariod, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. I edited your question to make it more to the point. If you feel like I changed it too much, you can always [edit] it back or add more information. Thanks for your time and effort and keep contributing!

Comment: Yes export the indesign project as a pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export the InDesign project as a PDF. Open in Acrobat and select print. Choose option to create 'Poster'. Here you can set 10x10 so you can at least have 100 pages in one 'poster' / page. Print as a PDF using AcrobatPDF in select printer option. 
So you'd have to this 3 times for your 300 pages in this case. Afterwards, you can stitch together these 3 x 100 pages in Illustrator, to make one huge page.. Keep a lookout for keeping things as readable as your project requires and having a computer that won't hit rock bottom RAM-wise while you do this.. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can export each page as a jpeg with the menu then import the jpegs back into indesign using a script.

There are a few scripts out there that do this – google "indesign contact sheet". If you're comfortable with applescript/javascript you can customize the scripts. This used to something you could do from Adobe Bridge, but it seems Adobe has discontinued it.